# Account balance cannot be less than -500 (C#)

Tags: c#, variables, math

I wanted to make a konto like in a bank. The account should not have less than ***-500***.
How do I bok the maximum possible amount and the residual value?
Best regards
Nicklas

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Konto
    {
        //Eigenschaften
        public double Kontostand { get; set; }
        public string Besitzer { get; set; }

        public void Einzahlen(double betrag)
        {
            Kontostand += betrag;
            Console.WriteLine("Es wurden {0} Eingezahlt!", betrag);
            Console.WriteLine("Der neue Kontostand beträgt " + Kontostand);
        }
        public void Auszahlen(double betrag)
        {
            if (Kontostand - betrag <= -500) //Kontostand kann nicht unter -500 fallen.
            {
                Kontostand ??? //Wie kann nich das maximale (-500) auszahlen lassen und den Rest bekommen?
                Console.WriteLine("Es können nicht {0} Ausgezahlt werden!", betrag);
                Console.WriteLine("Der neue Kontostand beträgt " + Kontostand);
            }
            else
            {
                //Kontostand -= betrag; // x = x - y
                //Console.WriteLine("Es wurden {0} Ausgezahlt!", betrag);
                //Console.WriteLine("Der neue Kontostand beträgt " + Kontostand);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What should be the outcome if the account is debited so that the balance falls below -500? You must specify the outcome you want.

Comment: Be aware that banks work primarily in terms of *transactions*. The balance is just the current running total of transactions against the account. Also, they wouldn't tend to use `double` for currency (often they'll shift the decimal point to the right to the smallest units they need to work in (cents or 100th of a cent) and just use integers)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you for your feedback I know, no bank uses double it's just an example about learning classes and methods. I'm still a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would have been far easier if you provided your actual question in english.

Anyway the following should give you the `betrag` as difference from the min `Konostand` (which is -500) and the old one.

```
public void Auszahlen(double betrag)
{
    if (Kontostand - betrag <= -500) //Kontostand kann nicht unter -500 fallen.
    {
        var oldKontostand = Kontostand;
        Kontostand = -500;
        Console.WriteLine("Es können nicht {0} Ausgezahlt werden!", betrag);
        betrag = Math.Abs(Kontostand - oldKontostand);
        Console.WriteLine("Der neue Kontostand beträgt " + Kontostand);
    }
    else
    {
        Kontostand -= betrag; // x = x - y
        Console.WriteLine("Es wurden {0} Ausgezahlt!", betrag);
        Console.WriteLine("Der neue Kontostand beträgt " + Kontostand);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!